# Does PMML support probability calibration?

Tags: python, java, probability-calibration

As I need to port a decision tree model from Python to Java, I would like to know whether PMML (Predictive Model Markup Language) supports probability calibration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with PMML, but probability calibration (or at least, the most well-known methods, Platt scaling and isotonic regression) can be viewed as a stacked ensemble, with the output of your model being fed into a univariate regression model.  PMML appears to support ensembling; see the fourth example at http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/MultipleModels.html